# Use ffmpeg to download stream from m3u8 file with a particular resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

I recently found how to download 'HLS' from a site and that works.

But one thing I could not find is if a particular site has available video in more than one resolution, say `1280x720` and `1920x1080`.

How can I tell 'FFMPEG' to download `1280x720` and not `1920x1080`?

This is the code I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://hsprepack.akamaized.net/videos/hotstarint/world/kwks6/1_2/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1540184067~exp=1540185867~acl=/*~hmac=a8945f016b594e1e2e4192ee05e2feaa5811c687d1891f69be1acc9057dd725f" -c copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a HLS master playlist using FFmpeg, all the variants are presented as numbered programs. You need to map the desired program.

So, first run

```
ffmpeg -i hls-link
```

to identify the program.

Then run,

```
ffmpeg -i hls-link -map 0:p:2 -c copy out
```

to download Program 2.

Comment: thank you very much it worked i had the idea it had something to do with  -map but i was lacking knowledge of p that stand for program which ring the bell when i saw the logs

Comment: How can I download all three resolutions...   Besides running this command three times?  Ideally I'd like to do them all in one command, so I assume I need multiple MAP params ?